# Das Verb "essen" mit nichttrennbaren Präfixen

Tags: prefix, past-participle, neologism

Das Verb *essen* hat eine kuriose Partizip-Perfekt-Form:

> ge**g**essen.

Zwar weiß ich nicht, woher das eingeschobene **g** kommt, aber ich meine mich zu erinnern, dass es etwas mit Reduplikation zu tun hat.

---

Wenn man ein nichttrennbares Präfix wie **zer-** oder **er-** einem Verb voranstellt, dann wird im Partizip Perfekt das **ge-** weggelassen:

> brechen - **ge**brochen
>   **zer**brechen - **zer**brochen
>
> kennen - **ge**kannt
>   **er**kennen - **er**kannt.

---

**Meine Fragen:**

- Nehmen wir einmal an, ich habe bei einem Wettessen einen Preis gewonnen. Habe ich mir den Preis dann *eressen* oder *er**g**essen*?
- Ich habe durch wildes Herumessen eine Torte zerstört. Habe ich sie *zeressen* oder *zer**g**essen*?

[Ich möchte nicht darüber diskutieren, ob diese Wortneuschöpfungen so benutzt werden. Gehen wir einfach mal davon aus, dass ich sie benutzen möchte. Mein Sprachgefühl spielt mir einen Streich und ich schwanke ständig hin und her zwischen den Varianten mit und ohne **g**.]

Für die Varianten mit **g** würde meines Erachtens sprechen, dass sie von *ge**g**essen* wie oben beschrieben abgeleitet sind.
Für die Varianten ohne **g** würde sprechen, dass die Form *ge**g**essen* wohl durch Reduplikation entstanden ist, die aber in den Verben *zeressen* und *eressen* nicht aufgetreten sein kann.

Comment: Die Torte hast Du zerfressen, wenn Du ein Verb brauchst, um den angerichteten Schaden an der Torte zu beschreiben, und nicht nur die Tatsache, dass Du welche gegessen hat. ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sehr interessante Frage!

## Zer- und eressen

Ich wollte schon vermuten, dass das Zusatz-g einfach daher stammt, dass *ge-essen* schwer zu sprechen ist, dann sind mir viele andere e-Verben eingefallen, zum Beispiel *geebbt, abgeebbt* … Soviel zu meiner schönen Theorie.

Dann habe ich mich an eine Con erinnert, auf der es ein Nudelsuppen-Wettessen gab, und mein Wölfchen hat sich den Sieg **ergessen** … so habe ich das damals gesagt, und so würde ich es heute auch wieder sagen. Das ist aber keine systematische Untersuchung.

Auch für *zergessen* würde ich eine Form mit *g* bevorzugen; rein spontan aus dem Bauch heraus.

Beachte aber auch, dass ich in der Regel Bairisch spreche, also von vornherein nur »I hob gessen«, ohne dass da ein zusätzliches *ge* vornedransteht. Preußisch-Sprecher würden das vielleicht anders machen.

## Veressen

Wie wäre es denn, wenn du dich an einer Mahlzeit *verisst*? Interessanterweise würde ich hier auf *ich habe mich **veressen*** ausweichen, um eine Verwechslung mit *vergessen* zu verhindern. Was für mich gleich die Frage aufwirft, woher eigentlich *vergessen* kommt, und ob dort ein Zusammenhang irgendeiner Art besteht?

## Erklärungsüberlegungen

Du unterstellst, dass die Reduplikation – sofern sie für das zusätzliche *g* verantwortlich ist (was ich nicht weiß) – nicht auftreten sollte, wenn eine Vorsilbe vor dem Verb steht. Aber warum sollte das gelten? Ein kurzer Blick auf die Wikipedia hat mir gesagt, dass die Reduplikation von Perfektformen ein altes, indogermanisches Phänomen ist, dass sich durch so verschiedene Sprachen wie Sanskrit, Altgriechisch und Latein zieht. Im Vergleich dazu sollte die Synthese neuer Wörter durch Vorsilben ein eher junges Phänomen sein; zumal es sich in uns nah verwandten Sprachen wie Englisch kaum findet.

Ich würde in dem Zusammenhang eher vermuten, dass die »alte« Reduplikation als intrinsischer Bestandteil des entsprechenden Verbs gesehen würde, und die »junge« Vorsilbe diese ältere Struktur nach Möglichkeit nicht stört. Schließlich werden auch alle anderen Merkmale unregelmäßiger Verben durch zusätzliche präfixierung nicht beeinträchtigt (*laufen - lief - gelaufen; verlaufen - verlief - verlaufen*, nicht *verlaufte*; laut Wikipedia ist das *ie* in *lief* auch auf Reduplikation zurückzuführen). Das Beispiel *ver(g)essen* zeigt aber auch, dass diese Regel gerne nicht gilt, wenn sonst Verwechslungsgefahr bestünde.<sup>[1]</sup>

­

­

---

­

---

­

[1] Ich habe mich mal oberflächlich mit der Neuerfindung von Sprachen auseinandergesetzt. Eine Website, die ich bei Bedarf gerne wiederfinden kann, hat auf die Nützlichkeit von historischen Lautverschiebungen für Sprachverwandtschaften hingewiesen. Unter anderem wurde der Fall behandelt »Was passiert, wenn zwei Wörter gleicher Art aber verschiedener Bedeutung und ursprünglich unterschiedlicher Aussprache durch Lautverschiebung gleich ausgeprochen werden?« Die vier Möglichkeiten waren: Die Wörter vermengen sich, eines der Worte verschwindet aus dem Sprachgebrauch, die Wörter werden gleichlautend aber mit unterschiedlicher Bedeutung, oder *das Wort, das sich verändern sollte, verweigert die Veränderung, um unterschiedbar zu bleiben*.